# Apache2 Web Server only recognized locally, does not work externally

Tags: apache2, webserver

I just installed apache2 this morning and am able to start the server and correctly
pull up the sample webpage at http://localhost.

I am behind a router so I set the router up for port forwarding to the proper server computer.

However, when I enter http:// to access my page into my browser, it does not work, and says server not found.

Can anyone please suggest what might be the problem here? This is a typical installation of desktop Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to access the web server from a machine on the other side of your router since you mentioned that you are port forwarding to the ubuntu server. Is it possible the router has a firewall which is blocking port 80 (http)? Is it possible you have a firewall installed on the Ubuntu server like firestarter that might be blocking port 80? Can you access the page from another machine on your internal network?

Comment: I can access the page from another machine on my internal network with no problem.

Comment: I don't have a firewall, pretty much this is a fresh install of desktop ubuntu 12.04.  I will check to see if there is a router firewall, thank you.

Comment: Some ISPs block port 80 - you might try running the web server on a different port and accessing the page that way `http://host:port`

Comment: Also, it does not seem to be a router issue, as I connected my server directly to the ISP, bypassing the router to check this.  The page still did not pull up.

Comment: Can you confirm that your ISP isn't blocking port 80?  Many do.

Comment: http://www.canyouseeme.org/ <-- Says my ISP is not blocking port 80.

Comment: I am running the server as "sudo" is it possible this is causing a problem?

Comment: You said other machines on your internal network could access it which suggests there is a problem in the routing from the other network to your machine, or that your machine has a firewall rule that is disallowing access from other networks.  I'm not using the default 12.04 apache conf files since I upgraded and it kept my old one, I'd have to poke through that to see if there could be a `deny` rule in there or something.

Comment: It turns out the apartment complex im living in has a cable modem that the maintenance controls and I don't have access to.  Thank you for helping to pinpoint this, I had forgotten about this.